# Graphviz Dot, mix directed and undirected/ in-coming out-going overlay

Tags: graphviz, dot

can't believe this question has not been asked, but I just can't find the solution.

I have a graph which will look like a tree:

```
A->B
B->A
A->C
C->..
[...]
```

The problem is that I get two arrows A->B and B->A but they are not on top of each other, which makes the whole graph look messy. For the actual directed edges everything is fine.

What I'd like is e.g.: A<->B->C

I've tried 
    graph [ splines = false ]
but then none of the arrows are bend anymore, what later on is a problem, too.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

the answer above almost did it.

```
A->B [style=invis]
B->A [dir=both]
```

W/out the [invisible] my tree would collapse.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You may try replacing

```
A->B
B->A
```

with

```
A->B
A->B [dir=back]
```

In case you want only one arrow pointing in both directions, use

```
A->B [dir=both]
```